# How to handle ajax in a mvc controller class

Tags: php, jquery, model-view-controller

I have the following `switch` statement that gathers variables from an AJAX call:

```
$_GET['button_type'];//The type of button Bio/ Posts
$_GET['first_name'];
$_GET['last_name'];
switch ($_GET['button_type']) {
    case "Bio":
    $model ->getBio();
        break;
    case "Posts":
    $model ->getPost($_GET['post_time']);
        break;
}
```

This is the AJAX call, using jQuery, after the user clicks on a button.

```
$.ajax({

  type: "GET",
  url: "fqlController.php",
  data: {first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, button_type: button_type},
  success: function(msg){
                 bio = msg;
                 $(button).text(bio);
                 button.slideDown("slow");
           }

});
```

Up until now, I've seen AJAX being handled in PHP script files without classes. Usually, it would be a `switch` statement that returns some text in an `echo` statement. After reading the tutorial, [PHP Master's MVC tutorial](http://phpmaster.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/), which shows the controller as a class and the index file creating the classes for the view model and controller with the following code,

```
<?php
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);
echo $view->output();
?>
```

my question is: how can I create a controller class that will be able to handle AJAX requests (execute a a `switch` statement), as well as, have other functions in the controller class that will be executed when an object of the controller class gets created? Is this even possible or do I have to regulate my AJAX handling to a separate file, one which doesn't have a class in it?

Comment: Ajax in MVC controllers is not different then simple requests. What changes is the form of response - thus, the view part.

Comment: So would I put the switch statement in the view? rather than calling the model I would call the controller?

Comment: @AustinDavis everything works the same in AJAX, the only thing is that the browser location doesn't change, so the content that would've been echoed/output is instead returned to your success callback as a string

Comment: To PHP, it's just any url being called. There is almost no difference between a normal request and an Ajax request. They are executed in the same way regarding PHP. The only difference is a header that allows you to detect if it was an Ajax call in the first place, but you don't have to use that.